# Best Approach for Developing a Cross-Platform Mobile App alongside a Django Web App?

Tags: django

I’m currently working on building a Django app, and I anticipate that it will eventually require a cross-platform mobile app as well.

While the Django web app can be designed to be mobile responsive, I’m considering the option of developing a native app. I’ve done some research, and it seems like React Native could be a good choice. However, I’m open to suggestions since React Native involves a completely different world and language compared to Django and Python.

I’d appreciate any recommendations or insights you may have regarding the best route to take for building a native mobile app alongside my Django app.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there are no really good Python based libraries to make a hybrid (Android / IOS) mobile application. Some of the best options (also with the most community support) you have are the following

- Flutter -- Flutter is very up and coming now and could be a good add on skill for you to pick up.
- React Native -- Same as flutter, a good additional skill
- Ionic -- Supports Javascript frameworks, so if you already know ReactJS or Angular, you can use that to make hybrid mobile applications.